# Deep Copy Constructor for binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, copy-constructor, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I am trying to create a deep copy of my binary tree data structure in C++. The problem is the code I am using only seems to be giving me a shallow copy (which seems to cause problems with my deconstructor).

the code below is my binary tree copy constructor:

```
BinaryTreeStorage::BinaryTreeStorage(const BinaryTreeStorage &copytree):root(NULL)
{
    root = copytree.root;
    copyTree(root);
}

BinaryTreeStorage::node* BinaryTreeStorage::copyTree(node* other)
{
    //if node is empty (at bottom of binary tree)
    /*
        This creates a shallow copy which in turn causes a problem 
        with the deconstructor, could not work out how to create a 
        deep copy.
    */
    if (other == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    node* newNode = new node;

    if (other ->nodeValue == "")
    {
        newNode ->nodeValue = "";
    }

    newNode->left = copyTree(other->left);
    newNode->right = copyTree(other->right); 

    return newNode;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Here is the deconstructor that throws a memory exception (which i believe is because of the shallow copy i do above)

```
BinaryTreeStorage::~BinaryTreeStorage(void)
{
    try
    {
        destroy_tree();//Call the destroy tree method
        delete root;//delete final node
    }
    catch(int &error)
    {
        cout << "Error Message : " << error << endl;
    }
}
void BinaryTreeStorage::destroy_tree()
{
    destroy_tree(root);
}
void BinaryTreeStorage::destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    //Recursively work way to bottom node 
    destroy_tree(leaf->left);
    destroy_tree(leaf->right);
    //delete node
    delete leaf;
 }
}
```

Comment: Assuming nodeValue is string, you need to allocate memory for newNode->nodeValue and copy value from other->nodeValue to newNode->nodeValue

Comment: and how do i do that? 
sorry for the noob responce :P

Comment: Next to deep copying the root (see answers), you are also not passing the value if it is not an empty string.  You probably want `node* newNode = new node(*other);`

Comment: that didnt seem to work either still throws a memory exception - Unhandled exception at 0x5f0865ca (msvcr100d.dll) in binarytree.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee2.

Comment: It's called "destructor". "Deconstructing" is what you do in philosophy class.

Comment: @Kerrek SB thanks your comment has fixed all my problems :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not performing a deep copy of your root node, only its children.

Shouldn't it be:

```
root = copyTree(copytree.root);
```

?

EDIT: **In addition**, you destroy the `root` twice:

```
destroy_tree();//Call the destroy tree method

//once here
//remove this line
delete root;//delete final node
```

and

```
if(leaf!=NULL)
{
   //Recursively work way to bottom node 
   destroy_tree(leaf->left);
   destroy_tree(leaf->right);

   //one more time here
   delete leaf;
}
```

**If you only do one of these fixes, the problem won't be solved.**

Comment: I tried that, there was no errors until it hit the deconstructor, gonna post my deconstructor In a second.

Comment: @BrianPeach have you tried debugging the copy constructor? Are the nodes built correctly.

Comment: It do perform deep copy but not save it, which is in fact a case of memory leak.

Comment: @BrianPeach see edited answer. You're deleting the root twice.

Comment: @wuliang a deep copy is when the `this` object copies all information from a parameter. If the info is not saved in `this`, how can you call it a deep copy?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore the nodes build correctly because i can print out the copy of the binary tree with no problems

Comment: @Luchian Grigore i just commented out "delete root;" and still got the same memory exception

Comment: @Luchian Grigore yea was just testing your answer

Comment: @BrianPeach so you kept **both** changes? Post the full code to www.ideone.com then.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore i am running both of your fixes and getting this error - Unhandled exception at 0x5f0fad84 (msvcp100d.dll) in binarytree.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee.

Comment: @BrianPeach post the full code to ideone and get it to crash there.

Comment: @BrianPeach don't edit the question here with radical changes, or posted answers won't make sense any more. Use ideone as I asked you. You have to help us help you.

Comment: @BrianPeach so post the header file here - http://ideone.com/21mGJ - click on clone and edit the code. It has to compile and crash.

Comment: @BrianPeach almost there. I've modified it a bit - http://ideone.com/ldF7D - but there's no crash. Add the code in `main` which generates the crash.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore http://ideone.com/uLof7 this is the main method (you can comment out the part for ArrayStorage to make it compile.

Comment: in ideone.com/uLof7 on line 97, you do `ArrayStorage arrayStorage4 = arrayStorage3;` which does a shallow copy

Comment: @stefaanv the code that is in the main i am not allowed to change but i have to create the classes to work with it though you are right that also creates a shallow copy please see the code that i have used to try and make it deep :S http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482998/create-a-deep-copy-of-an-array-c

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think we can directly using the copy constructor to recursively deep copy the tree. Suppose the class is defined as follows:

```
class TreeNode {
public:
  TreeNode() : value(), count(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
  TreeNode(const TreeNode &);

  ~TreeNode();

  TreeNode &operator=(const TreeNode &);

  // Other members...

private:
  std::string value;
  int count;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
  // Note that the valid state for the `left` and `right` pointer is either
  // `nullptr` or a subtree node. So that we must check these pointers every
  // time before dereferencing them.
};
```

Then the copy constructor is

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(const TreeNode &n)
    : value(n.value), count(n.count), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
  if (n.left)
    left = new TreeNode(*n.left);  // recursively call copy constructor
  if (n.right)
    right = new TreeNode(*n.right);  // recursively call copy constructor
}
```

The recursion will be stopped at the leaf node, since both its two children are `nullptr`.

And so does the destructor.

```
TreeNode::~TreeNode() {
  delete left;  // recursively call destructor on left subtree node
  delete right;  // recursively call destructor on right subtree node
}
```

When `left` or `right` is `nullptr`, `delete` will do nothing, so that the recursion will be stopped.

You can see the complete code from [**here**](https://github.com/jaege/Cpp-Primer-5th-Exercises/blob/master/ch13/13.28.cpp).