# Create a deep copy of an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor, copy-constructor

I am try to solve some problems in my program and it would appear that there is either a problem with my copy constructor or with my destructor. I am getting a memory exception.

any help would me appreciated
Thanks

```
ArrayStorage::ArrayStorage(const ArrayStorage &a):readArray(a.readArray),arraysize(a.arraysize)
{
    readArray = new string[arraysize]; //create the array

    memcpy (readArray,a.readArray,sizeof(string)*arraysize);//Copy the values of bytes from the location pointed at by the souce and destination.
}

ArrayStorage::~ArrayStorage(void)
{
    delete[](readArray);//deconstuctor to delete the array.
}
```

would this be a better way to copy the array other than memcpy :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < arraysize ; i ++)
    {
        readArray[i] = a.readArray[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't just `memcpy` random objects, you need to actually copy them with their copy operators.

`string` most likely holds a pointer to heap-allocated storage. If you copy it bitwise, calling the destructor on the original string invalidates the "copied" string's data.

Use something like `std::copy` to do this properly.

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::copy(a.readArray, a.readArray+arraysize, readArray);
```

Comment: how would i use std::copy without using vectors(not allowed to use vectors for this work)?
sorry if thats a noobish question.

Comment: Edited. BTW, your initialization if `readArray` in the initializer list is useless in the copy constructor - you're overwriting it in the body.

Comment: thanks for that however i am getting 2 errors, 
1. no instance of overloaded function "std::copy" matches the argument list.
2. no operator "+" matches these operands :S

Comment: What is the type of `readArray`,  how did you declare it? (BTW your for loop should work just fine too.)

Comment: Then it should work. Works here. There is no reason for that `+` operator error, it's pointer arithmetics. Please show how you declared that member.

Answer (score 6):

I would not advice you to copy strings the way you do. As the string holds reference to heap memory you in fact copy the pointers and so the strings in both arrays are sharing memory. This is not very c++-ish and quite dangerous. I would advice you to use the assignment operator or copy constructors for the strings(yes do a cycle).

Comment: Or even use a `vector<string>` where performing a deep copy is as easy as `vector<string> newlist = oldlist;`.

Comment: @Benj agreed - this is a better option but not very related to the question - he is asking why this is not working not how to do it :)

Comment: what would be the best way to copy the array?

Comment: i would love to use vector for this but i am not allowed to unforunately :\ what would be the best other way?

Comment: @BrianPeach use a vector<string> as proposed by Benj instead of a dynamic array. If you do need to copy array as you described it use std::copy(a.readArray, a.readArray + a.arraysize, readArray); NOte: you still have to allocate the memory for readArray before calling copy.

Comment: @izomorphius well i cannot use vector<string> but i will try this std::copy, though how do you allocate the memory for the read array? sorry i am new to c++ :P

Comment: you already allocate it in your code - using the 'new' operator.

Answer (score 0):

The strings also have dynamic memory, so you'd have to go through each string and make a copy of it.

A fix would be copying each string inside of your array instead of memcopy. The exception is from two different strings having the same pointer to a piece of memory and both trying to free it.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't make any sense. First you initialize your members to the values passed by the object to copy, through the initializer list. Then you allocate memory for the very same members and copy everything again.

Most likely you are copying junk data into an uninitialized pointer. Get rid of the initializer list `:readArray(a.readArray),arraysize(a.arraysize)`.

Comment: well the initializer list was done to get rid of some of the parasoft errors i was getting.

Comment: @BrianPeach The initializer list was the reason you got a memory exception.