# Copy dynamically allocated array of objects with copy constructor

Tags: c++, memory, copy

Assume I have a following class, basically an ordinary array wrapper:

```
 template<class T>
 SimpleArray {
   T * array;
   SimpleArray(): T(NULL) {}
   SimpleArray(T * array_) {
     // what goes here?
   }
   // TODO: copy constructor and copy assignment
   ~SimpleArray() {
     delete[] array;
   }
 };
```

How do I copy elements from one array to another? If it was a simple type, I could just use something like `memcpy`, and it would work just fine. But what if `T` is a complex type that requires deep copying? If, say, `T` has a member array, than shallow-copying it would create several `T` objects pointing to the same resource, which is a disaster.

Basically, I need some way to create a deep copy of an array. Any suggestions?

I know I could use something from the standard library, but there's a reason I don't. `SimpleArray` is designed to give an easy access to the internal storage of my objects in form of `T*`. As far as I am concerned, no STL container supports such functionality.

Comment: Well, first you need to know the size of `array_` before you can do anything...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482998/create-a-deep-copy-of-an-array-c

Comment: @nikhil Oh, indeed, looks like it. Thanks! I guess, my search wasn't as good.

Comment: std::vector gives you access in form of `T*`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/

Answer (score 1):

It's inadvisable to roll your own dynamic arrays. If all you need is access to the underlying data via a T*, then you can use [vec.data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) (c++11 only), or &vec.front().